# Проблема при создании папки на сервере

Tags: файлы, php

Создаю для каждого пользователя папку для его изображений, при этом проверяю существование папки так:

```
 $filpath = "img/p".$uId;
 if(file_exists($filepath) == '0'){mkdir("img/p".$uId);}
```

При первом обращении к странице с данным кодом, создается папка, но при повторном, выдает ошибку:

> `Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in Z:\home\mysite.loc\www\setting.php on line 40`

на линии 40 как раз проверка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите внимательно что возвращает функция [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: if(file_exists($filepath)){mkdir('img/p'.$uId);} - если прописать так, ошибку не выдает, но ведь это неправильно, создавать папку, когда она уже есть.

Comment: __Внимательно__. Она возвращает TRUE или FALSE. 0 она не возвращает никогда, поэтому условие всегда выполняется ваше.

Comment: 0 === false